# SQL doesn't work on a large sample

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to solve a challenge and came up with the solution. The solution which I have written works for small dataset but it doesn't seem to work fine for larger ones. Could someone help me where am I doing wrong?

I am facing trouble with calculating the unique users for each day (second column in the output). The rest of the logic works fine.

> Julia conducted a 15 days of learning SQL contest. The start date of the contest was March 01, 2016 and the end date was March 15, 2016.
>
> Write a query to print total number of unique hackers who made at least  submission each day (starting on the first day of the contest), and find the hacker_id and name of the hacker who made maximum number of submissions each day. If more than one such hacker has a maximum number of submissions, print the lowest hacker_id. The query should print this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date.
>
> Input Format
>
> The following tables hold contest data:
>
> Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name
>   of the hacker.

[image]

> Submissions: The submission_date is the date of the submission, submission_id is the id of the submission, hacker_id is the id of the hacker who made the submission, and score is the score of the submission.

[image]

Sample input

[image]

[image]

For the following sample input, assume that the end date of the contest was March 06, 2016.

Hackers Table: Submissions Table:

```
**Explanation :-**
```

On March 01, 2016 hackers , , , and  made submissions. There are  unique hackers who made at least one submission each day. As each hacker made one submission,  is considered to be the hacker who made maximum number of submissions on this day. The name of the hacker is Angela.

On March 02, 2016 hackers , , and  made submissions. Now  and  were the only ones to submit every day, so there are  unique hackers who made at least one submission each day.  made submissions, and name of the hacker is Michael.

On March 03, 2016 hackers , , and  made submissions. Now  and  were the only ones, so there are  unique hackers who made at least one submission each day. As each hacker made one submission so  is considered to be the hacker who made maximum number of submissions on this day. The name of the hacker is Angela.

On March 04, 2016 hackers , , , and  made submissions. Now  and  only submitted each day, so there are  unique hackers who made at least one submission each day. As each hacker made one submission so  is considered to be the hacker who made maximum number of submissions on this day. The name of the hacker is Angela.

On March 05, 2016 hackers , ,  and  made submissions. Now  only submitted each day, so there is only  unique hacker who made at least one submission each day.  made  submissions and name of the hacker is Frank.

On March 06, 2016 only  made submission, so there is only  unique hacker who made at least one submission each day.  made  submission and name of the hacker is Angela.

Sample Output

```
2016-03-01 4 20703 Angela
2016-03-02 2 79722 Michael
2016-03-03 2 20703 Angela
2016-03-04 2 20703 Angela
2016-03-05 1 36396 Frank
2016-03-06 1 20703 Angela

Schema & Data :-
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/844928

```
Solution :-


SELECT A.submission_date, A.cnt, B.hacker_id, B.name 
  FROM
    (
        SELECT submission_date, COUNT( DISTINCT hacker_id ) AS cnt
          FROM submissions
         WHERE submission_date = '2016-03-01'
         GROUP BY submission_date 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT submission_date, COUNT( DISTINCT hacker_id )
          FROM
            (
                SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, convert( date, A.submission_date ))  AS submission_date, A.hacker_id
                  FROM 
                    (
                       SELECT submission_date, hacker_id
                         FROM submissions
                       GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
                     ) A
                INNER  JOIN  
                    (
                         SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, convert( date, submission_date )) AS new_submission_date, hacker_id
                           FROM submissions
                          GROUP BY DATEADD(day, -1, convert( date, submission_date )) , hacker_id
                     ) B
              ON A.submission_date = B.new_submission_date
             AND A.hacker_id = B.hacker_id  
            ) Z
        GROUP BY submission_date
    ) A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, h.name
      FROM
    (
        SELECT submission_date, hacker_id 
          FROM
        ( 
            SELECT submission_date, hacker_id,cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY submission_date ORDER BY cnt DESC, hacker_id ) AS rn
              FROM 
            (
             SELECT submission_date, hacker_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
               FROM submissions
              GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
            ) Z
        ) Y
        WHERE rn = 1
    ) s
    INNER JOIN
    hackers h
    ON s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
) B
ON A.submission_date = B.submission_date
;
```

Comment: I added sqlfiddle link to create schema and data....

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it doesn't seem to work fine"?

Comment: What relations are with `colleges` table in your sqlfiddle ?

Comment: This looks a LOT like homework to me. As such we can point you in the right direction but you should be doing this yourself. Or if it is a challenge as you say how can you submit an entry if others had to write it for you?

Comment: The unique users count doesn't produce right result for a larger input dataset. I am just curious what's the wrong I am doing even though the logic seems correct to me.

Comment: @OtoShavadze Colleges is not required for this problem. Only hackers and submissions are the two tables needed.

Comment: I suggest starting up SQL profiler and going through the Query plan

Comment: @Carra how is the execution plan going to help debug a logic error?

Comment: Guys, the unique users part is what I am looking for... I added the explanation which I have written in my SQL. Pls tell me whats the wrong I am doing...

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
  unique_hackers_on_dates AS
(
   SELECT   
      Submissions.submission_date,
      Submissions.hacker_id,
      COUNT(1) subs_per_hacker_per_day,
      MAX(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY submission_date) max_subs_per_day
   FROM
      Submissions
   GROUP BY
      Submissions.submission_date,
      Submissions.hacker_id      
), 
   hacker_with_max_sub AS
(
   SELECT
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date,
      MIN(hacker_id) min_hacker_id
   FROM
      unique_hackers_on_dates
   WHERE
      unique_hackers_on_dates.subs_per_hacker_per_day = unique_hackers_on_dates.max_subs_per_day
   GROUP BY
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date
), 
   dates AS
(
   SELECT   
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date, 
      unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id
   FROM
      unique_hackers_on_dates
   WHERE
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date = CAST('2016-03-01' AS Date)
   UNION ALL
      SELECT   
         unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date, 
         unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id
      FROM     
         dates
      INNER JOIN
         unique_hackers_on_dates 
         ON dates.hacker_id = unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id AND
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, dates.submission_date) = unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date
), 
   consec_hackers as
(
   SELECT 
      submission_date,
      count(1) num_consec_hackers
   FROM 
      dates
   GROUP BY
      submission_date
)
SELECT
   consec_hackers.submission_date,
   consec_hackers.num_consec_hackers,
   hacker_with_max_sub.min_hacker_id,
   Hackers.name
FROM
   consec_hackers
INNER JOIN
   hacker_with_max_sub
   on consec_hackers.submission_date = hacker_with_max_sub.submission_date
INNER JOIN
   Hackers 
   ON hacker_with_max_sub.min_hacker_id = Hackers.hacker_id
ORDER BY 
    consec_hackers.submission_date;
```

Comment: I just started working on this problem and I was curious if there was a more effecient way to do this other than using the sub queries?

Answer (score 1):

Check on [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/HGUGB63617) the next query:

```
WITH
  a AS
  (
    SELECT
      submission_date,
      hacker_id,
      COUNT(*) AS submissions_by_hacker,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY submission_date) AS sequence_number_by_date,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY hacker_id ORDER BY submission_date
      ) AS sequence_number_by_hacker,
      RANK() OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY submission_date ORDER BY count(*) DESC
      ) AS rank_by_hacker_submissions
    FROM #submissions
    GROUP BY submission_date, hacker_id
  ),
  b AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      MIN(IIF(rank_by_hacker_submissions = 1, hacker_id, NULL)) OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY submission_date
      ) AS min_hacker_id
    FROM a
  )
SELECT
  b.submission_date,
  h.hacker_id,
  COUNT(*) AS quantity_of_hackers_who_made_at_least_submission_each_day,
  h.name AS hacker_name
FROM b JOIN #hackers AS h ON b.min_hacker_id = h.hacker_id
WHERE b.sequence_number_by_date = b.sequence_number_by_hacker
GROUP BY b.submission_date, h.hacker_id, h.name
ORDER BY b.submission_date, h.hacker_id;
```

**Output:**

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|   submission_date   | hacker_id | quantity_of_hackers_who_made_at_least_submission_each_day | hacker_name |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 01.03.2016 00:00:00 |     20703 |                                                         4 | Angela      |
| 02.03.2016 00:00:00 |     79722 |                                                         2 | Michael     |
| 03.03.2016 00:00:00 |     20703 |                                                         2 | Angela      |
| 04.03.2016 00:00:00 |     20703 |                                                         2 | Angela      |
| 05.03.2016 00:00:00 |     36396 |                                                         1 | Frank       |
| 06.03.2016 00:00:00 |     20703 |                                                         1 | Angela      |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results;
CREATE TABLE #Results
([Number of Hackers that had a Submission]                 INT,
 SubmissionDate                                            DATE,
 [Greatest # of Submissions by Hacker (lowest ID if tied)] INT,
 [Hacker Name with Most Submissions]                       VARCHAR(50)
);
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE;
DECLARE my CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT
           submission_date
    FROM submissions;
OPEN my;
FETCH NEXT FROM my INTO @CurrentDate;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Results
               SELECT a.hackers [Number of Hackers that had a Submission],
                      a.SubmissionDate,
                      b.Submission_Count [Greatest # of Submissions by Hacker (lowest ID if tied)],
                      b.Hacker [Hacker Name with Most Submissions]
               FROM
               (
                   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_ID) hackers,
                          @CurrentDate [SubmissionDate]
                   FROM submissions
                   WHERE submission_date = @CurrentDate
               ) a
               JOIN
               (
                   SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(submission_id) Submission_Count,
                                b.name [Hacker],
                                submission_date
                   FROM submissions a
                        JOIN hackers b ON a.hacker_id = b.hacker_id
                   WHERE a.submission_date = @currentDate
                   GROUP BY b.name,
                            a.hacker_id,
                            submission_date
                   ORDER BY COUNT(submission_id) DESC,
                            a.hacker_id
               ) b ON a.SubmissionDate = b.submission_date;
        FETCH NEXT FROM my INTO @CurrentDate;
    END;
CLOSE my;
DEALLOCATE my;
SELECT *
FROM #Results;
```

Don't usually like using cursors, but it's quick for small data, and easy to evaluate on a per date basis..

Your results are close, but not the same as what I got, don't have the time to diagnose your query, so use this one to compare and contrast.

Considering you posted this on Mar 17th, I'm guessing and hoping if this was homework, its well past due now... and I didn't help you cheat on something..

Good luck!

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select submission_date ,( SELECT COUNT(distinct hacker_id)  
                    FROM Submissions s2  
                    WHERE s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date AND 
                    (SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) 
                     FROM Submissions s3 
                     WHERE s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id AND  
     s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date) = dateDIFF(s1.submission_date , '2016-03-01')) ,

        (select hacker_id  from submissions s2 
         where s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date 
           group by hacker_id 
         order by count(submission_id) desc , hacker_id limit 1) as hack,
    (select name from hackers where hacker_id = hack)
    from 
    (select distinct submission_date from submissions) s1
    group by submission_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select big_1.submission_date, big_1.hkr_cnt, big_2.hacker_id, h.name
from
(select submission_date, count(distinct hacker_id) as hkr_cnt
from 
(select s.*, dense_rank() over(order by submission_date) as date_rank, 
dense_rank() over(partition by hacker_id order by submission_date) as hacker_rank 
from submissions s ) a 
where date_rank = hacker_rank 
group by submission_date) big_1 
join 
(select submission_date,hacker_id, 
rank() over(partition by submission_date order by sub_cnt desc, hacker_id) as max_rank 
from (select submission_date, hacker_id, count(*) as sub_cnt 
from submissions 
group by submission_date, hacker_id) b ) big_2
on big_1.submission_date = big_2.submission_date and big_2.max_rank = 1 
join hackers h on h.hacker_id = big_2.hacker_id 
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple query. Use the Sample data provided below for testing

```sql
--- This CTE pulls the unique hackers who made atleast 1 submission per day
WITH cte_c(submission_date,hacker_id) AS
(
SELECT submission_date,hacker_id FROM Submissions WHERE  submission_date = '2020-03-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT A.submission_date,A.hacker_id FROM Submissions A
JOIN cte_c B ON A.submission_date = DATEADD(dd,1,B.submission_date) and A.hacker_id = B.hacker_id
WHERE A.submission_date > '2020-03-01'
)
-- This CTE gives the hackers who made maximum submissions each day and assigns rank 1 to min(hacker_id)
,cte_h as
(
SELECT submission_date,hacker_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY submission_date ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, hacker_id) rnk
FROM Submissions
GROUP BY submission_date,hacker_id
)
SELECT c.submission_date,c.hackers_per_day,h.hacker_id,ha.name 
FROM (SELECT submission_date, COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id) as hackers_per_day FROM cte_c GROUP BY submission_date) C
JOIN cte_h H on c.submission_date = H.submission_date  and rnk = 1--and c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
JOIN Hackers ha  ON h.hacker_id = ha.hacker_id
ORDER BY c.submission_date
------- Sample Data ---------------------------------------
create table #Hackers
(
hacker_id int,
name varchar(10)
)

create table #Submissions
(submission_date date,
hacker_id int)

insert into Hackers Values(1,'Test1'),(2,'Test2'),(3,'Test3'),(4,'Test4'),(5,'Test5')
insert into Submissions Values('2016-03-01',1),('2016-03-01',2),('2016-03-01',3),('2016-03-01',4),
('2016-03-02',2),('2016-03-02',2),('2016-03-02',3),('2016-03-02',4),('2016-03-02',3),
('2016-03-03',5),('2016-03-03',1),('2016-03-03',2),('2016-03-03',4),('2016-03-03',1),
('2016-03-04',1),('2016-03-04',2),('2016-03-04',5),('2016-03-04',2)
```